# How do I limit tk.DoubleVar to a number of significant figures

Tags: python, tkinter

I am learning/trying out `tkinter`, and trying to use a `DoubleVar` to store the data from a `Scale` widget and have it output through a `Label`.

This works fine, but it displays to a much higher significant figure level than I would like. Is this something I should control on the `Label` side or the `DoubleVar` side, and how would I do this?

```
    coefficient_of_resitution_value = tk.DoubleVar()
    coefficient_of_resitution_slider = ttk.Scale(coefficient_of_restitution_frame,
                                                 from_ = 0,
                                                 to = 1,
                                                 orient = "horizontal",
                                                 variable = coefficient_of_resitution_value,
                                                 style = "white_background_scale.Horizontal.TScale")
    coefficient_of_resitution_slider.grid(column = 0, row = 1, columnspan = 1, sticky = tk.NSEW)

    coefficient_of_resitution_display = ttk.Label(coefficient_of_restitution_frame,
                                                  textvariable = coefficient_of_resitution_value,
                                                  background = "#FFFFFF",
                                                  font = ("Calibri", 16))
    coefficient_of_resitution_display.grid(column = 1, row = 0, sticky = tk.NSEW)
```

Comment: It is better to provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the way is to round the value to what you want inside the callback of `command` option:

```py
    coefficient_of_resitution_slider['command'] = \
        lambda val: coefficient_of_resitution_value.set(round(float(val), 4))
```

Comment: While that has worked in limiting the number of significant figures, it still swaps between the number of significant figures when it reaches numbers like 0.8000 (which comes out as 0.8 regardless of the significant figures chosen). This causes the grid to jiggle around. Is there a way to make the number stick to its significant figure count even if the rest of the digits are zeros?

Comment: @LetAbetheUnknown Change `round(float(val), 4)` to `f'{float(val):.04f}'`.